# Grouping multiple dates from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Been having a tough time with the bellow transformation in python.
Was using excel but the table is getting too big for the calculation.
The table consists of rows of processes and their stages (20 stages) with their dates and status per date for each line like so:

| id | Stage 1 Status | Stage 1 Completion | Stage 2 Status | Stage 2 Completion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Complete | 2021-01-15 14:15:00 | Lost | 2021-02-28 13:48:00 |
| 2 | Complete | 2021-01-21 15:00:00 | Complete | 2021-01-21 15:00:00 |
| 3 | Complete | 2021-02-03 14:08:00 | Open |  |

my goal is to group the data per year and per month in year and count how many processes are at what stage like bellow:

Completed

|  | Stage1 | Stage2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-21 | 2 | 1 |
| Feb-21 | 1 | 0 |

Open

|  | Stage1 | Stage2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-21 | 0 | 0 |
| Feb-21 | 0 | 1 |

First time posting on here so any feedback on the question raised is more than welcome.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Python/Pandas workflow that will help you get what you need. The comments in the code will guide you.

I recommend running this line-by-line in the interpreter and inspecting the changes to variables to see what's going on.

Note that there's usually more than one way to do things in Pandas: sometimes it's just a matter of style but also Pandas is always evolving and coming up with better functionality. Suggestions for improvement are welcome.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# create dataframe from example
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'Stage 1 Status': ['Complete'] * 3,
  'Stage 1 Completion': ['2021-01-15 14:15:00', '2021-01-21 15:00:00', '2021-02-03 14:08:00'],
  'Stage 2 Status': ['Lost', 'Complete', 'Open'],
  'Stage 2 Completion': ['2021-02-28 13:48:00', '2021-01-21 15:00:00', np.nan]
})

# convert string to a suitable date-time type
df['Stage 1 Completion'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Stage 1 Completion'])
df['Stage 2 Completion'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Stage 2 Completion'])

# === PART 1: get a basic result dataframe with correct groups and counts ===

# fill blanks (NaNs) in Stage 2 completion (presumably all from Open status) with the Stage 1 completion date
df['Stage 2 Completion'] = df['Stage 2 Completion'].fillna(df['Stage 1 Completion'])

# format completion times as 01-21, 02-21, etc.
df['Stage 1 Completion Formatted'] = df['Stage 1 Completion'].dt.strftime('%m-%y')
df['Stage 2 Completion Formatted'] = df['Stage 2 Completion'].dt.strftime('%m-%y')

# temporary dataframes for each stage with the counts
df1 = df.groupby(['Stage 1 Status', 'Stage 1 Completion Formatted'])['Stage 1 Completion'].count().rename('Stage 1 Count').to_frame()
df1.index.names = ['Status', 'Completion']
df2 = df.groupby(['Stage 2 Status', 'Stage 2 Completion Formatted'])['Stage 2 Completion'].count().rename('Stage 2 Count').to_frame()
df2.index.names = ['Status', 'Completion']

result_df = df1.join(df2, how='outer').fillna(0) # missing => zero count


# === PART 2: make the results look right ===

# first, split the results on Open vs Complete; ignore Lost for now
complete_df = result_df.loc[('Complete', slice(None),), :].reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
open_df = result_df.loc[('Open', slice(None),), :].reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

# next, find the union of MonthYears (i.e., strings like '02-21') across all status types and make that the index for each DF
# note that lexicographical string sorting matches the natural ordering (i.e., '01-21' comes before '02-21')
t = sorted(result_df.index.get_level_values('Completion').unique())

# with the new common index, make sure that missing entries are represented with zero count
complete_df = complete_df.reindex(t).fillna(0.0)
open_df = open_df.reindex(t).fillna(0.0)

# counts are integers (preferably), not floats
complete_df['Stage 1 Count'] = complete_df['Stage 1 Count'].astype("Int32")
complete_df['Stage 2 Count'] = complete_df['Stage 2 Count'].astype("Int32")
open_df['Stage 1 Count'] = open_df['Stage 1 Count'].astype("Int32")
open_df['Stage 2 Count'] = open_df['Stage 2 Count'].astype("Int32")

# next, create a column with date formatted as Jan-21, Feb-21, etc. and make that the index
complete_df['MonthYear'] = complete_df.index.map(lambda z: datetime.strptime(z, "%m-%y").strftime("%b-%y"))
complete_df = complete_df.reset_index(drop=True).set_index('MonthYear')
open_df['MonthYear'] = open_df.index.map(lambda z: datetime.strptime(z, "%m-%y").strftime("%b-%y"))
open_df = open_df.reset_index(drop=True).set_index('MonthYear')

print('=== Completed ===')
print(complete_df)

print('')

print('=== Open ===')
print(open_df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got it to work for all three Categories. One question if I may. Is there away around not filling the NaN dates?

Comment: You need a back-reference to the Stage 1 Completion date to assign the Stage 2 Opens to a date bucket. I used the NaN fill for this but any other approach to get the same reference would work. If you want to avoid polluting the original DF, you could make a copy and work with it, leaving the original DF unchanged. Alternatively, you could add an extra column with the NaNs filled, leaving the original column unchanged, then drop the extra column once you're done.

Answer (score 0):

- started by simulating dataframe, 41 columns. 20 stage dates, 20 stage statuses
- split columns into a multi-index to allow for **stage** to be stacked as part of row index
- truncate date to month
- now simple groupby / aggregate logic
- finally cleanup by sorting column names

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# simulate data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        **{"id":range(1,201)},
        **{
            f"Stage {n} Status": np.random.choice(["Open", "Lost", "Complete"], 200)
            for n in range(1, 21)
        },
        **{
            f"Stage {n} Date": np.random.choice(
                pd.date_range("15-jan-2021", freq="16H", periods=60), 200
            )
            for n in range(1, 21)
        },
    }
)

dfa = df.copy().set_index("id")
# convert columns to multiindex of stage and status or date
dfa.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    np.array([c.rsplit(" ", 1) for c in dfa.columns]).T
)


dfa = (
    # make stage part of row index
    dfa.stack(0)
    .reset_index()
    # get month start of date times
    .assign(month=lambda d: (d["Date"] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1)).dt.normalize())
    # the required counts...
    .groupby(["Status", "level_1", "month"])
    .agg({"Date": "count"})
    # make stage a column again
    .unstack("level_1")
    .droplevel(0, 1)
    # order columns from stage 1 ... stage 20
    .pipe(lambda d: d.reindex(sorted(d.columns.tolist(), key=lambda x: int(x.split(" ")[1])), axis=1))
)

dfa
```

| Status | month | Stage 1 | Stage 2 | Stage 3 | Stage 4 | Stage 5 | Stage 6 | Stage 7 | Stage 8 | Stage 9 | Stage 10 | Stage 11 | Stage 12 | Stage 13 | Stage 14 | Stage 15 | Stage 16 | Stage 17 | Stage 18 | Stage 19 | Stage 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Complete | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 29 | 31 | 26 | 32 | 31 | 35 | 23 | 33 | 36 | 30 | 22 | 26 | 45 | 28 | 31 | 29 | 30 | 23 | 30 | 38 |
| Complete | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 30 | 35 | 20 | 35 | 33 | 41 | 36 | 29 | 39 | 46 | 42 | 46 | 29 | 40 | 33 | 36 | 34 | 37 | 42 | 35 |
| Lost | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 25 | 21 | 36 | 27 | 26 | 26 | 17 | 24 | 26 | 20 | 28 | 31 | 21 | 27 | 20 | 37 | 27 | 25 | 20 | 28 |
| Lost | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 37 | 35 | 45 | 38 | 43 | 33 | 43 | 41 | 36 | 36 | 51 | 33 | 29 | 39 | 40 | 35 | 39 | 46 | 32 | 30 |
| Open | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 32 | 28 | 37 | 32 | 38 | 38 | 38 | 36 | 30 | 28 | 31 | 26 | 28 | 34 | 35 | 31 | 28 | 31 | 32 | 29 |
| Open | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 47 | 50 | 36 | 36 | 29 | 27 | 43 | 37 | 33 | 40 | 26 | 38 | 48 | 32 | 41 | 32 | 42 | 38 | 44 | 40 |